# Extract HTML from CDATA node in iPhone

Tags: objective-c, iphone, touchxml

```
<item>
<data>
  <![CDATA[
  <p>Test</p>
  <p><strong>Hi!</strong><br />Hello.</p>
  ]]>
</data>
</item>
```

Using TouchXML/NSXMLParser How can i extract only the HTML part into a string/appropriate data format so that I can display it in a UIWebView?

It's definitely possible: http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/issues/detail?id=36&can=1&q=cdata

Comment: No XML parser should parse CDATA sections anyway http://www.w3schools.com/xmL/xml_cdata.asp

Comment: CDATA is the only way you can store HTML or other data containing "<" and "&" characters, I think what the link means is that the parser should not *automatically* parse the node as a normal node. CXMLNode is implemented so that it can handle parsing CDATA.

Comment: You can certainly store literal `<` and `&` without a CDATA section, through normal `&`-escaping. You should read the textual content of the `<data>`, not caring whether it came from inside a CDATA section or just plain text.

Comment: Get the CDATA element, get everything inside and display in UIWebView ?

Comment: @bobince Yes indeed!... HTML encoded (&raquo;) works too!
@stefanB yes, actually thats what I'm trying to do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TouchXML will parse it automatically.  If you retrieve the stringValue of the CXMLElement you will get the full "raw" html back, properly formed.

Comment: Indeed! Automatic CDATA parsing and clean HTML into NSString to put it into UIWebView use `[myWebView loadHTMLString:myHTMLString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mysite.com"]];`